# Disable switching window on different desktop

Tags: macos, workspace, osx-spaces, mission-control

I want to prevent switching window on other desktop in this case:

- Open app A background and app B foreground on desktop 2
- Switch to desktop 1
- Switch to another window of app A on desktop 1
- Switch to desktop 2
- There is a first window of app A foreground for some reason

How to prevent MacOS from switching to app A on all desktops after switching to just one window of the app on one desktop?

MacOS 13.2.1

Comment: I don't have Ventura, but I can't repro this behaviour. How are you switching Spaces? Ctrl[num], trackpad swipe? Default behaviour ought to be that any Space you traverse to should bring forward the last app that was frontmost in that Space. [This doesn't apply if you Cmd/Tab to switch apps, or if any Space is fullscreen].

Comment: A proviso on the above default is that if there is no other app in the Space you traverse to, then the only app in that Space will come to the front, the last resort being Finder.

Answer (score 4):

The Mission Control system setting "When switching to an application, switch to a space…" is misleading and always doesn't work as described.  My best guess is that the behavior can be overridden per app, and consequently the system setting sometimes has no effect, but that's merely a guess. For example, ⌘+tabbing to Mail will switch to a desktop with an open mail viewer regardless of the global setting.

There is, however, an under-the-hood Dock preference that can be set via Terminal.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool FALSE
killall Dock
```

Note that this disables the behavior entirely, which may not suit everyone.  Reverse it with:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool TRUE
killall Dock
```

Answer (score 2):

The document
[Work in multiple spaces on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac)
has this text in the section "Assign apps to spaces":

> By default, when switching to an app, the desktop automatically switches to a space that has open windows for the app. For example, if you create a new TextEdit document in Desktop 3, but TextEdit windows are already open in Desktop 2, your new document opens in Desktop 2. To change this setting, choose Apple menu  > System Settings, click Desktop & Dock in the sidebar, go to Mission Control on the right, then turn “When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application” on or off.

Changing this setting might fix this behavior.

EDIT: This setting had no effect on the poster's problem.
I'm leaving this answer here as it might help other users.

Comment: This is kind of the inverse of what the OP seems to be asking. They're switching Spaces, not Apps.

Comment: It's a little different case. Mac does not switch space by itself when I switch to some app on some desktop (space). Mac switches app on all another spaces to foreground instead of switch to window of that app only on current space.

Comment: So this setting has no effect on the problem?

Comment: Yep, no effect turned on or off

Comment: I think your problem is the one discussed in the post [Prevent macOS from bringing all windows to front when switching to an app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339884/prevent-macos-from-bringing-all-windows-to-front-when-switching-to-an-app). Let me know if you like any of the answers in this post and I will rewrite my answer accordingly.

Comment: The linked QA is also 'app-driven' not 'Spaces-driven', so is again not relevant. It's a different rule-set when you call a Space rather than when you call an app directly.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'm not on the Mac, so have difficulty understanding the difference. It seems to me that the problem is that when one switches the app in one space, this implicitly switches to the same app in other spaces, which is the problem discussed in this last link.

Comment: I guess it's one of those things you get used to the foibles of;) The user is not 'switching app' per se. Spaces & apps are separate entities, though are 'joined at the hip'. Switching app may switch Space & switching Space may bring a different app frontmost. Spaces was never designed to allow any single app to be on more than one Space - which clouds the issue somewhat. However, switching Space alone should not in itself bring an app to the front, unless it was already frontmost in that Space, or is the only app open on that Space.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, and I turned the option you describe off. It's still happening... any ideas how to stop this? I want to click on an application and not switch desktops.

Comment: @Well...: Try the other answers in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by unsetting Desktop assignment to the specific Desktop. Try to set Options->Assign To->None in Dock for application A as on screenshot below.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]